# Is packaging type 'pom' needed when not using project aggregation (multimodule)?

Tags: inheritance, maven-2, packaging, pom.xml

I want to inherit the dependencies of a (parent) `pom.xml` in a child project in Maven 2.2.1; i.e. use project inheritance. It seems it is necessary to change the default packaging type from `jar` to `pom` in this case.

However, doesn't [the Maven2 documentation](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Project_Inheritance) state that the packaging type `pom` is necessary for project aggregation, i.e. multimodule projects which use submodules, but not for project inheritance?

```
<project>
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>example</groupId>
 <artifactId>example-parent</artifactId>
 <version>1</version>

 <dependencies>
   <dependency>
     <groupId>log4j</groupId>
     <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
     <version>1.2.14</version>
   </dependency>
 </dependencies>
</project>

<project>     
 <parent>
   <groupId>example</groupId>
   <artifactId>example-parent</artifactId>
   <version>1</version>
 </parent>

 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>example</groupId> 
 <artifactId>example-child</artifactId>
</project>
```

But if you call Maven (e.g. `mvn clean`) with the above configuration, you get an error:

```
Project ID: example:example-child

Reason: Parent: example:example-parent:jar:1 
 of project: example:example-child has wrong packaging: jar.
Must be 'pom'. for project example:example-child
```

On other other hand, with the following entry:

```
<project> 
 ... 
 <packaging>pom</packaging>
 ... 
</project>
```

in the parent `pom.xml`, Maven can be executed without any error.

Is this behavior of Maven correct?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As documented in the [Inheritance](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Inheritance) section of the [POM Reference](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html):

> The packaging type required to be `pom` for *parent* and *aggregation* (multi-module) projects.

So Maven's behavior seems correct to me (and the error message is nicely self explaining).

Answer (score 2):

If you're just wanting to inherit dependencies then I don't think it needs to be type 'pom'.
You could have it jar and simply specify it as a dependency of the project which you have as child. However you wouldn't then have the parent/child relationship which is what prevents your parent project being a type other than 'pom'.

To be clear, you inherit the dependencies of all your dependencies ( transitive dependencies ).

Answer (score 0):

As noted by Pascal, the behaviour is correct.

If you're still looking for means to share dependencies between modules, you can consider bundling up the dependencies in question into a pom, and then having your modules both depend on that new "dependencies" pom.

See [Maven Book Section 3.6.1](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-best-practice.html#pom-relationships-sect-grouping-deps) for more details.