# The parent project must have a packaging type of POM

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am trying to create a new maven module. Parent project is a Web Service and has pom.xml.

How can I fix this error and create a new module?

[image]

Comment: I can't see the image so this is based solely on the error message in your title. Make sure the parent POM has `<packaging>pom</packaging>`. By default, it's JAR.

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193789/is-packaging-type-pom-needed-when-not-using-project-aggregation-multimodule

Answer (score 30):

Update your parent project's **pom.xml** by replacing packaging property from `jar/war` to `pom` as following...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>project-group</groupId>
    <artifactId>webservice</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>project-name</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>  
</project>
```

Answer (score 6):

Open POM.xml in eclipse Id->Overview->ArtifactId->Packaging(Select POM from dropdown)->Save then create new Maven module.